# Magnolia CMS - Public user registration Notification

Tags: magnolia

I am using Admin-supervised registration (Never) strategy as Public user registration. With this approach, Admin needs to enable the user, but admin is not getting an email. Is this the expected behaviour or admin should get an email to notify new user has been registered. If that is not out of the box feature, How can I enable admin to get an email when the user is registered ?

Also, I would like to know can I mix and match Registration after mail notification and Admin to enable. Then we can make sure provided email is correct as well and Admin to control to access.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting the notification, you can simply add custom strategy that would wrap the ootb provided one and send email on top ... or you can add observer on the users workspace and configure it to call `MailCommand` upon new disabled user being created in the repo. Whichever of the two suits you better.
As for combining two of the existing strategies, the simplest way to achieve that is by writing your own that will indeed do combination of the two provided out of the box. Since each of the functionalities you desire is there, it should be rather simple to combine them in one class.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Thaks @Jan, I have looked the source code. Could you please elaborate more what you mean by "you can add observer on the users workspace and configure it to call MailCommand upon new disabled user being created in the repo"?

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the class and method triggered when user click the activate link once the user gets the activation email after registration ?

Comment: For more info on observation and how to set ip up, please see documentation at https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Observation+module

Comment: Mail registration strategy and code that is behind it is afaik described also in documentation at https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Public+User+Registration+module#PublicUserRegistrationmodule-Mailregistrationstrategy